# Redirecting subdomain to utorrent server

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4, subdomain, mod-proxy

I have the subdomain: ut.domain.com

The virtual host is set up below.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName ut.domain.com

ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```

This lets me access the webui of uTorrent server with `ut.domain.com/gui`
How can I modify it to hide the trailing `/gui` that is needed at the end to access the webui.
I tried adding `/gui` after the port number but it ends up giving me a blank page instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply proxying to the subdirectory?

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/gui
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/gui
```

Comment: Yes I have. As I mentioned in the question, the page becomes blank. Edit: Sorry, the page says `invalid request`